# Android Wear asking Handheld for Data

Tags: android, wear-os

How do I get the Wear app to ask for data from the handheld when the Wear app is launched?

Should the handheld run a service to listen for messages sent by the Wear?

Edit: Or perhaps, another way to look at this question is... what if my handheld does not have a UI but the watch needs live information from the phone when the wear app is open -- say for example, retrieving the current battery status.

Comment: check out the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html it describes how to handle communication to between the wear app and the handheld.

Comment: you must check when the wear and the device are connected (you can do that in your app)

Comment: @Aegis: Thanks but I have already studied the documentation provided in the link. It does say how communications are handled, but does not specifically mention how the wear can get data from the handheld when the wear app is launched.

Comment: that totally depends on the use case of the handheld app, so with the battery example on every change of the percentage post a message on the data api. The wear api will receive it.

Comment: @Aegis: Okay, maybe the battery level isn't such a good example. How about a live remote data source? It wouldn't be wise for the handheld to periodically retrieve data every 10 seconds to send to the wear if the wear app isn't open.

Comment: The data API is made with this in mind, so sending a message to all the nodes even when they are not connected or running should guarantee arrival. even if its not real time. The handheld post messages and the wear app subscribes and vice versa. Kinda like an eventbus.

Comment: @mushroom Did you find any solution? I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: @DroidLearner Yes, I did. Basically, I had to create a WearableListernerService on both the mobile and the wear. Both should have the `com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER` intent filter set to trigger the service.

Comment: @mushroom Can you add the snippet please?